# Service fabric Statefulservice throwing error at CreateServiceRemotingListener

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I am getting the below error. I have added required nuget package Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting v3.0.472.

> 'VotingDataService' does not contain a definition for
>   'CreateServiceRemotingListener' and no extension method
>   'CreateServiceRemotingListener' accepting a first argument of type
>   'VotingDataService' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

```
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Communication.Runtime;
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting;
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Remoting.Runtime;
using Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services.Runtime;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Fabric;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace VotingDataService
{
    public interface IVotingDataService2 : IService
    {
        Task<int> AddVote(string voteItem);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The FabricRuntime creates an instance of this class for each service type instance. 
    /// </summary>
    internal sealed class VotingDataService : StatefulService, IVotingDataService2
    {
        public VotingDataService(StatefulServiceContext context)
            : base(context)
            { }

    public Task<int> AddVote(string voteItem)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<ServiceReplicaListener> CreateServiceReplicaListeners()
    {
        return new[]
        {

            new ServiceReplicaListener(context =>
                this.CreateServiceRemotingListener(context))
        };
    }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to implement an interface that extends `IService`. The extension method works on `IService`.
(`IMyService` in the example)

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting).

Comment: I have updated the above code and implemented IService  I still get the same error.

Comment: I figured out what the problem is I as creating a stateful service under  ".Net Core 2.0" when I created the same stateful service under ".Net Framework". Is this not supported in .Net Core 2 ?

Comment: Oh, make sure to use Remoting V2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting#how-to-use-remoting-v2-stack

Comment: @LoekD - I am facing the same issue but unable to understand the significance of Remoting V2. The Microsoft page is not that clear either. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: This is because dotnet core apps only support remoting v2.